# Top N sorted rows with GROUP BY?

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, top-n

I have the following `transaction` table:

```
customer_id, category, product_id, score
```

I'm grouping by `customer_id` and `category` to create a list of `product_id-score` map pairs:

```
SELECT
    s.customer_id,    
    s.category,
    collect_list(s.pair) 
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            customer_id,
            category,
            map(product_id, score) AS pair
        FROM
            transaction
        WHERE
            score > {score_threshold}
    ) s 
GROUP BY
    s.customer_id,
    s.category
```

Now I want to take this a step further. For each group, I'm looking to retain just the top `n` pairs, sorted by `score` (descending order).I tried the `OVER (PARTITION BY...ORDER BY)` by I'm running into problems.

Note: the `transaction` table is partitioned by `category`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
        s.customer_id,    
        s.category,
        collect_list(s.pair) 
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id, category ORDER BY score desc) as RowId 
                customer_id,
                category,
                map(product_id, score) AS pair
            FROM
                transaction
            WHERE
                score > {score_threshold}
        ) s 
        where s.RowId < n
    
    GROUP BY
        s.customer_id,
        s.category
```